# How to draw a pie chart and a column chart in a single page

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I need to draw a pie chart and a column chart in a single page, when I use
the package 'bar' it can draw a column chart but not a pie chart

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

when I use 'corechart' package it will draw piechart but not possible to draw a column chart (but able to draw bar chart)

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

How can I draw both graphs in a single page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart','bar']});//add multiple packages
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMaterial); //call there corresponsing draw functions
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);//call there corresponsing draw functions
function drawMaterial() { // add each function definition
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City', '2010 Population', '2000 Population'],
    ['New York City, NY', 8175000, 8008000],
    ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000, 3694000],
    ['Chicago, IL', 2695000, 2896000],
    ['Houston, TX', 2099000, 1953000],
    ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000, 1517000]
  ]);

  var materialOptions = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Total Population',
      minValue: 0,
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'City'
    },
    bars: 'horizontal'
  };
  var materialChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));//draw on different-different elements
  materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);
}

function drawChart() {// add each function definition

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2],
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));//draw on different-different elements

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```